# Typescript does not throw error when required type gets set with optional field

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code piece:

```
  let bank_account = await createBankAccount({
      acc_number: 'AT' + group.id,
      allow_out_payment: true,
      bank_id: bank.data[0],
      partner_id: group.odoo_id,
   })
```

My problem here is that `partner_id` is of type number and `group.odoo_id` is optional

[image]

[image]

Typescript does not mark this as an type error. `group.odoo_id`could be undefined but typescript does nothing. Whats wrong here?

Comment: We may need more context on your code.  Perhaps TS has narrowed the type down so that where this occurs it knows for sure that `odoo_id` has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to throw an error in those cases, you need to set the option `strictNullChecks` to `true` in the tsconfig.json.

Then, if you're sure that the current value is defined, you have to mark it like that:

```
partner_id: group.odoo_id!,
```